# selenium chromedriver and chrome binary wont connect even they match versions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First: I have been working with selenium for some time now, and I am NOT a newbie here - nevertheless I have encountered an issue that I just can't solve for some hidden reason...
I am on ubuntu 20.04 and I have downloaded chrome beta + chromedriver with exact same version + created webdriver with chrome path + chromedriver path specified as follows:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
chrome_options.binary_location = google_chrome_beta_bin
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
selenium_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver_bin)
```

I get the following exception:

```
Message: session not created
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
```

Any clue what is wrong here? Chrome beta about dialog says it's version 88.... and chromedriver was downloaded for that specific version, still I get this error. Did work for 87...

Answer (score 0):

That was quick :)

removing the debugging port solved the issue. Previously / on windows machine - it worked. In fact setting the remote-debugging-port was recommended as solution to another bug.